# open_basedir how much you can trust it?

Tags: security, vps, open-basedir

I have a VPS from godaddy and 3 sites on it. 1 of it is my main subject which i have taken every precaution in the code (100% hand made) to secure it (PHP/Mysql/Javascript) and to have it run smoothly.

Now for the 1st time we giving one of the other 2 accounts to a 3rd party to make a website. I do not know/trust them so i want to secure mine as good as possible meaning that **I want to complete cutoff access to the filesystem / php etc. of my account**.

I have mod_security and suPHP built-in to apache but when I turned PHP 5 Handler from **dso to suphp (Apache suEXEC is on)** one folder's htacess went bananas and did not work resulting in file not found. I read about some modifications I have to do in htaccess files and also fix files' permissions (I tend to give 777 to folders containing useruploads -like photos, docs which is ok for everyone to see so no problem- ofc not want anyone but me deleting them) cause supposedly 777 folders/fiels will trigger error.

So did not want to get into that process and found about the WHM>Security Center >Security Center> PHP **open_basedir Tweak**, which states that 
'*PHP's open_basedir protection prevents users from opening files outside of their home directory with php*'

Is this enough? I mean it will block only opening my files? Will it protect me from someone trying to copy his own malicious php files to my directory and then running it to wreak chaos?

I am kinda new at this (1st time I encountered that issue ) and would like some feedback from your experience

Comment: @sc0p I have only one VPS administrated with WHM and inside in the 'list accounts' i have 3 accounts, 1 is my main site and 2 others which have old sites which we will give away for renovation, PHP 5 Handler is dso which from what i found means single instance with 'nobody' owner.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be completely sure, but you seem to be concerned for 1 site you own and you want to protect (main) and another (2) site(s) that are going to be created by a 3rd party you don't trust.

I think anyone would need way more info to tell you how they could access your "main" site. Basically if they are running on the same instance of PHP/Apache it means they share the same user, that means that any vulnerability found in any of the "dangerous" sites can affect your "main" site.

But you say they are VPS, so the sites should be not related at all, living in different virtual servers. In that case, there seems to be not reasons to worry.